# Does "Portal site connection" do anything in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, navigation

Does anyone know if "Portal site connection" can be used on standard  master page (seattle)? Is it completely useless unless you use custom master page?

[image: SharePoint 2013 portal site connection function]

In SharePoint 2010 I could find a connected portal in this "Folder":

[image: SharePoint 2010 portal site connection]